# What does wikipedia use to scale?

Tags: lamp, scale, wikipedia

Being the 5th most visited site in the world, and serving millions of pages to tens of millions of users daily, does wikipedia use anything else in the back-end to scale to those numbers?

Or is it just really good code?

Is it also true that they have just over a hundred (or a few) hundred servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little outdated (2006): 
[Wikipedia:
cheap & explosive 
scaling with LAMP](http://swe.web.cs.unibo.it/twiki/pub/WikiFactory/AntonelloDiMuroThesis/Wikipedia-cheapandexplosivescalingwithLAMP.pdf) (PDF)